Properly use React's `cache` with NextJS Server-Side Rendering
I am building a NextJS application using its AppRouter functionality. For some of the pages in my application, I want to set the page metadata (for SEO and other purposes) using NextJS's generateMetadata function. The page metadata will depend on the data fetched from the database. The page will also display the content based on the same data.
To fetch the data, I have written a utility function which is something like this:
const getData = async (
  id: string,
): Promise<result: MyModel> => {
    const result = await getDataFromDatabase(id);
    return result;
}

and this is how I am using it in generateMetadata function and in my page.
export async function generateMetadata({
  params,
}: Props): Promise<Metadata | undefined> {
    const data = await getUserDetails(params.id);
    return {
        title: data.title,
        description: data.description,
    };
}

export default async function Page(props: Props) {
    const { params } = props;
    const result = await getData(params.id);
    return (
        <div>
            <div>Title is `${result.title}`</div>
            <div>Description is `${result.description}`</div>
        </div>
    )
}

This is all fine. But the problem is that my getData method will be called twice - first time in generateMetadata method and then in Page.
I went through some links and it was recommended that I use ReactJS's cache functionality to cache the result of getData method. Based on this, I modified my getData method like the following:
const getData = cache(async (
  id: string,
): Promise<result: MyModel> => {
    const result = await getDataFromDatabase(id);
    return result;
});

This again works well however the following caught my attention (Ref):

cachedFn will also cache errors. If fn throws an error for certain
arguments, it will be cached, and the same error is re-thrown when
cachedFn is called with those same arguments.

The way I understand this is that if for some reason my getData function throws an error (let's say because of some transient issue in the database), then I will get the same error back for the duration of the cache. This does not sound right to me. If indeed that is the case, then how can we circumvent this.
Another question I have is that if the data is changed, how can we automatically revoke the cache so that the next call will fetch the data from the database?
